# Javascript permission denied error when using Atalasoft DotImage

Tags: asp.net, dotimage

Have a real puzzler here. I'm using Atalasoft DotImage to allow the user to add some annotations to an image. When I add two annotations of the same type that contain text that have the same name, I get a javascript permission denied error in the Atalasoft's compressed js. The error is accessing the style member of a rule:

In the debugger (Visual Studio 2010 .Net 4.0) I can access
   h._rule
but not
   h._rule.style

What in javascript would cause permission denied when accessing a membere of an object?

Just wondering if anyone else has encountered this. I see several people using Atalasoft on SO and I even saw a response from someone with Atalasoft. And yes, I'm talking to them, but it never hurts to throw it out to the crowd. This only happens in IE8, not FireFox.
Thanks, Brian

Updates: Yes, using latest version: 9.0.2.43666

By same name (see comment below) I mean, I created default annotations and they are named so they can be added with javascript later.

```
// create a default annotation
TextData text = new TextData();
text.Name = "DefaultTextAnnotation";
text.Text = "Default Text Annotation:\n double-click to edit";
//text.Font = new AnnotationFont("Arial", 12f);
text.Font = new AnnotationFont(_strAnnotationFontName, _fltAnnotationFontSize);
text.Font.Bold = true;
text.FontBrush = new AnnotationBrush(Color.Black);
text.Fill = new AnnotationBrush(Color.Ivory);
text.Outline = new AnnotationPen(new AnnotationBrush(Color.White), 2);
WebAnnotationViewer1.Annotations.DefaultAnnotations.Add(text);
```

In javascript:

```
CreateAnnotation('TextData', 'DefaultTextAnnotation');

function CreateAnnotation(type, name) {
    SetAnnotationModified(true);
    WebAnnotationViewer1.DeselectAll();
    var ann = WebAnnotationViewer1.CreateAnnotation(type, name);
    WebThumbnailViewer1.Update();
}
```

Comment: Lou from Atalasoft here.  That definitely sounds familiar.  What do you mean by have the same name?  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I created default annotations and they are named so they can be added with javascript later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in an earlier version that allowed annotations to be saved with the same unique id's.  This generally doesn't cause problems for any annotations except for TextAnnotations, since they use the unique id to create a CSS class for the text editor.  CSS doesn't like having two or more classes defined by the same name, this is what causes the "Permission denied" error.

You can remove the unique id's from the annotations without it causing problems.  I have provided a few code snippets below that demonstrate how this can be done.  Calling ResetUniques() after you load the annotation data (on the server side) should make everything run smoothly.

-Dave C. from Atalasoft

```
protected void ResetUniques()
{
    foreach (LayerAnnotation layerAnn in WebAnnotationViewer1.Annotations.Layers)
    {
        ResetLayer(layerAnn.Data as LayerData);
    }
}

protected void ResetLayer(LayerData layer)
{
    ResetUniqueID(layer);
    foreach (AnnotationData data in layer.Items)
    {
        LayerData group = data as LayerData;
        if (group != null)
        {
            ResetLayer(data as LayerData);
        }
        else
        {
            ResetUniqueID(data);
        }
    }
}

protected void ResetUniqueID(AnnotationData data)
{
    data.SetExtraProperty("_atalaUniqueIndex", null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I also got that from Atalasoft support, although without the explanation of creating css classes. I still have an issue - if I start with no annotations, create a couple of text annotations and then rotate, I get the protection error again. It appears my application is still creating with non unique ids. I am installing the latest hotfix again.

Comment: Dave C - Now I'm getting duplicate layers and annotations on the server side when the page is posted with a normal postback or with an asp.net ajax request. This occurres with the 9.0.2.43666 builds and with the 9.0.2.43718 builds. It did not occur with builds prior to that. I have submitted this to Atalasoft support with an example in the ftp folder named Case00040495